# EXT4-fs error on loop0

Tags: debian, ext4, dd, fsck, proxmox

I have Debian 10 with the latest Proxmox installed.

2 SSD with:

```
sda1: EFI
sda2: raid1 (/dev/md0)
sda3: swap
sdb1: EFI (clone of sda1)
sdb2: raid1 (/dev/md0)
sdb3: swap
```

After an update, I wanted to clone /dev/sda1 to /dev/sdb1 with dd, but I made an error and typed `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`. I cancelled it with Ctrl+C, did the right command `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1` and rebooted.

The system seems to work, but I have these errors in my log:

```
Feb 02 20:50:01 Yggdrasil kernel: EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup:1704: inode #174282: comm php: deleted inode referenced: 174769
Feb 02 20:50:01 Yggdrasil kernel: EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup:1704: inode #174282: comm php: deleted inode referenced: 174769
Feb 02 20:50:01 Yggdrasil kernel: EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup:1704: inode #174282: comm php: deleted inode referenced: 174769
Feb 02 20:50:01 Yggdrasil kernel: EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup:1704: inode #174282: comm php: deleted inode referenced: 174769
Feb 02 20:50:01 Yggdrasil kernel: EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup:1704: inode #174282: comm php: deleted inode referenced: 174769
Feb 02 20:50:01 Yggdrasil kernel: EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup:1704: inode #174282: comm php: deleted inode referenced: 174769
Feb 02 20:50:01 Yggdrasil kernel: EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup:1704: inode #174282: comm php: deleted inode referenced: 174769
Feb 02 20:50:01 Yggdrasil kernel: EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup:1704: inode #174282: comm php: deleted inode referenced: 174769
Feb 02 20:50:01 Yggdrasil kernel: EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup:1704: inode #174282: comm php: deleted inode referenced: 174769
Feb 02 20:50:01 Yggdrasil kernel: EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup:1704: inode #174282: comm php: deleted inode referenced: 174769
```

I ran `fsck` in rescue mode but didn't seem to find these errors as they continue to pop on the logs.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explaining The Error:**
 That error does not indicate a problem with a physical disk; `loop0` is a loopback device. Which is a block storage device that uses a file on disk as a backing store. A disk within a disk you might say. These loopback disks have their own filesystems and sometimes their own partition tables. So running fsck on the physical disks which hold them will not have any effect

**Solution**

Find the file which backs the loop device with `losetup -a | grep loop0` and run fsck on that

Answer (score 2):

Solved: I found the culprit. It was one of my lxc images.

I ran `e2fsck /var/lib/vz/images/100/vm-100-disk-0.raw` and now errors are gone.